# Mysql replication need to have two master servers

Tags: mysql, replication

I need to synchronize to databases one in my local site, the second on remote site.I think I can use MySql replication but I need to have two master servers (changes in any of them should be send to the other). Is it possible?

Comment: I dont think you would need 2 masters. Just one master and a slave would be enought for your case.

Comment: The first thing to consider is the latency between the two locations.

Comment: Sam, how can I bring changes from slave to master?

Comment: @Gayane Slave cannot update a master.

Comment: So why did you suggest to have master-slave instead of master-master?
I wrote "(changes in any of them should be send to the other)"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build a multi-master cluster but you need additional components on top of MySQL. I suggest to have a look at:

- http://mysql-mmm.org/
- http://codership.com/content/using-galera-cluster
- http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster

Please note however that multi-master replication has a cost in term of performance.

Comment: Thanks, this links are very useful. Is it possible to do this replication using phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I doubt it. You need a good DBA to setup such a configuration.